# Will there be an update to ManagedCuda for version 9.0 libraries?

Tags: managed-cuda

The latest changes to ManagedCuda were made about 5 months ago. Is the project still supported? Will there be updates? If not, what is a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The project is still alive, but the Cuda 9 update needs some more time: A lot of changes and not enough time :)

Comment: Thanks! I have been using your library since 2013, and it is super helpful. The old code works fine with CUDA 9; just updated the dll names for cuSparse, cuSolve, etc.